# mysql (mariadb) stored proc sql error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

[SQL Fiddle providing tables and current proc](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fb03/4)

I have two tables - a parent table and a table with meta data.  I have a stored proc (that I swear was working at one point) that converts the row-based data from the meta table into columns and merges the parent table with the row to column data using a left join.  I am now getting an Error 1064.

**Update: I output the query in the proc for debugging purposes and I discovered that the last row to column pivot never provides the column name (which is pulled from the metakey value).  It doesn't matter what the last column is, it's always getting cut off after n characters (It appears to be inconsistent as to how many chars before truncating)!  Here's the full output of the query.**

```
SELECT q.*,
MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'account_number', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `account_number`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'area', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `area`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'attachment_name', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `attachment_name`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'attachment_token', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `attachment_token`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'attachment_url', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `attachment_url`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'description', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `description`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'device_name', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `device_name`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'email', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `email`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'engine_files_attachment_name', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `engine_files_attachment_name`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'engine_files_attachment_token', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `engine_files_attachment_token`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'engine_files_attachment_url', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `engine_files_attachment_url`,MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'fname_lname', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS `fname_lname`,

/** THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE OCCURS **/
MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'how_connected_network', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS ,

m.json 
FROM support_ticket_queue q LEFT JOIN support_ticket_queue_meta m ON q.id = m.ticket_queue_id GROUP BY q.id
```

The proc:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `p_support_ticket_queue`()
BEGIN

SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(m.metakey = ''',m.metakey,''', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS ','`',m.metakey,'`'
        )
        ORDER BY m.metakey
    )
INTO @sql FROM
    support_ticket_queue_meta m;

SET @sql = CONCAT ( 'SELECT q.*,' , @sql , ' , m.json FROM support_ticket_queue q LEFT JOIN support_ticket_queue_meta m ON q.id = m.ticket_queue_id GROUP BY q.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling this proc returns the following error in response:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM support_ticket_queue q LEFT JOIN support_ticket_queue_meta m ON q.id = m.ti' at line 1
```

The overview information on the two tables are as follows:

```
support_ticket_queue (the parent table)
---------------------------------------
id (primary auto increment)
vertical (varchar)
created_on (datetime)
updated_on (datetime)


support_ticket_queue_meta
---------------------------------------
id (primary auto incremenet)
ticket_queue_id (foreign key to id from parent table)
metakey (varchar)
metavalue (text)
```

Comment: My guess is that MySQL is choking on whatever has been assigned to the `@sql` variable before the query which appears to be throwing the error.  In any case, has anything changed recently?  Have a look at the output from the `GROUP_CONCAT` query.

Comment: Here's what I've discovered - the 'MAX(IF(....)) AS ...' section never provides the value for the AS assignment for the last column that should be created.  For example, the last record in the meta table has a metakey of "how_connected_network".  But the proc is doing this:  "MAX(IF(m.metakey = 'how_connected_network', m.metavalue, NULL)) AS "

Comment: This sounds like a good start.  Play around with this piece of the proc separately until you have fixed it.  I can't post an answer because I don't have your data.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to spend some time tomorrow digging further into this.

Comment: You may be even able to answer your own question.  Ping me and I will upvote it.

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the data in your tables, sufficient to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello. I have just updated the post to include a link to a SQL Fiddle showing both of the tables and sample data as well as the stored proc.  I currently have the proc outputting the final select it is to execute.  You will notice that there seems to be a max variable length allowed?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fb03/4

Comment: solved it and posted answer.  has to do with the GROUP_CONCAT length limits.

Answer (score 0):

Did some debug testing and noticed the pattern of my GROUP_CONCAT getting truncated after 1024 characters.  Did some further searching online and discovered that there is in fact a 1024 length limit for GROUP_CONCAT.

By increasing group_concat_max_len value to a higher limit has resolved my issue.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 2500;
```